# Adding user in a group via Glue ETL job status failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, jobs

My Glue ETL job's status failed when I try to add my user *user_test* in the admin group: *admins* via my python script.

Python  content using boto3 addUser.py :

```
import boto3

glue_client = boto3.client('glue', region_name='eu-west-3')
iam_client = boto3.client('iam')    
group_name = 'admins'
user_name = 'user_test'    
response = iam_client.add_user_to_group(
    GroupName=group_name,
    UserName=user_name
)    
print('Adding user_test successfully')
```

Then :

```
aws glue create-job \
    --name privesctest \
    --role arn:aws:iam::93424712358:role/GlueAdmin \
    --command '{"Name":"pythonshell", "PythonVersion": "3", "ScriptLocation":"s3://zokulko-bucket/addUser.py"}'
```

*GlueAdmin*  has **AmazonS3FullAccess** and **AWSGlueServiceRole** and **glue.amazonaws.com** as a service principal.

Then I directly start the job in the cli :

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name privesctest
```

But then my user_test is not added into my admins group, what's wrong with my script?